# Pandas dropna method subset parameter - difference between specifying the column as a string and as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following sample df which I want to drop missing row for period1 column. I use dropna method with subset parameter as a list (test1) and as a string (test2), both returns the same result.

I try to find out -

1. Would specifying the subset parameter as a string (since I only have one column) cause any issue?
2. If yes, is it due to different version of Python (currently I am using 3.7)
3. If yes, is it due to running the code on different OS (currently I am running on window, not on a server)
4. What would be the potential issue?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = { 'item':['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
  'period1':[np.nan,222,5555,123],
  'period2':[4567,3333,123,123],
  'period3':[1234, 254,9993,321],
  'period4':[999,525,2345,963]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

test1 = df1.copy()
test2 = df1.copy()

# period1 in a list
test1.dropna(subset=['period1'],inplace=True)

# period1 as a string
test2.dropna(subset='period1',inplace=True)
```

Comment: It is better using list ,since the new version of pandas will not accept str

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I assume. Do you know starting from which version pandas will not accept str as a subset parameter?